# C# & SQL : how to update table without refreshing DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, sql-update

I always use

```
DataGridView.DataSource = (DataTable)tbl;
```

But this method is completely refresing the Datagridview something like selectedrows, scrollbar position, backColor etc.. I only want to update cell data from SQL witouth  full  datagridview refresh

For Example uTorrent has a table like datagridview, and in some cells x KB/s values always refresing but torrentdatagrid is static. there is No scroll moving, no selection dissapearing etc.

Can you help me to do this?

I'm sorry for my bad English. Thanks.

Comment: Surely you can iterate on rows and column and set new values. But why not only save selected index of datagridview and reselect it after setting datasource?

Comment: #Reza Aghaei, Because if I do that as you say, Some actions happenig on screen something like (after datasource refresh:) scroll is going top of table and when reselect executing sroll position is changing again. When these are happinig, users see all of actions.  I thing, Yes it will work but this is bad thing.

Comment: So what if some records deleted from or added to datasource?

Comment: I will only update datas. if deleted or added (insert) some data I must change datasource. My Question is only for updating data. is iteration methot row by row the only Solution?

Comment: Does your table have a primary key?

Comment: yes. id int primary key(1,1)

Answer (score 1):

If your table has a primary key, and you want only to update existing/add new rows, you can use [DataTable.Merge Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

Initially

```
dataGridView.DataSource = initial_data_table;
```

Update

```
((DataTable)dataGridView.DataSource).Merge(new_data_table);
```

**UPDATE:** The method above is the simplest, but as mentioned in the comments, it has side effects due to the `Merge` method optimizations which suppress the change notifications during the operation and raising `ListChanged` event with `ListChangedType.Reset` at the end. So, here is a simple and effective method that does the trick, based on [DataTable.LoadDataRow Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5abehtz(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
foreach (var dataRow in newTable.AsEnumerable())
    table.LoadDataRow(dataRow.ItemArray, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
```

And a sample proving that:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Samples
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var form = new Form();
            var dg = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = form };
            var data = GetData();
            dg.DataSource = data;
            var updateTimer = new Timer { Interval = 200, Enabled = true };
            updateTimer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
            {
                foreach (var dr in GetData().AsEnumerable())
                    data.LoadDataRow(dr.ItemArray, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
            };
            Application.Run(form);
        }
        static DataTable GetData()
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Score", typeof(int));
            dt.PrimaryKey = new[] { dt.Columns["Id"] };
            var random = new Random();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
                dt.Rows.Add(i, "Player #" + i, random.Next(1, 100000));
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It resets the grid scroll position and selected record. it refreshes the grid.

Comment: @RezaAghaei My tests show that only horizontal scroll position is reset. Vertical scroll position and selected record are not affected.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by refreshing the grid - the grid needs to be updated, this is so far the easiest way to do so, I see no other side effects than horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @IvanStoev I tried again and unfortunately it behave like when you set datasource of grid. It changes the position of scrolls and selected record.

Comment: @IvanStoev I think the best working idea is updating cells of first dataTable using loop. I updated dataGridView cells using a loop, but better  to update first dataTable and since dataTable supports 2-way databinding, updates will show in dataGridView without changing the scroll position and selected row.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I'm not quite sure why are you explaining the 2-way data binding since my idea is obviously based on that concept. You were right thought for the side effects, but the way you are attacking the issue looks too complicated for that job. See my updated answer for a simpler method of doing the same.

Comment: @IvanStoev That message was for informin the OP :) Your knowledge and art in windows forms and Databinding  is admirable +1 :)

Comment: @IvanStoev by the way, check the solution with an identity column too. I think you will receive some exception when using ItemArray.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thank you, and please excuse me - I totally forgot that OP is supposed to read that too :-) But I think to stop here, OP seems to get solved the problem is his own way, and to be honest, I'm not very interested in this particular problem domain, since I never used `DataTable`s in my project (too generic for my taste), neither `DataGrid(View)` (we are using a professional UI component suite). Nice to talk to you, have a great day!

Comment: @IvanStoev Never mind, Me too :) Have a nice day too:)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I slog to explain problem. I m sorry. but, this code solved my problem,

```
            for (int i = 0; i < dg.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < dg.Columns.Count ; j++)
                {
                    dg.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = NewDataTable.Select("ID=" + dg.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value)[0][j].ToString();
                }
            }
```

first column is ID Primary key column. I m Updating by a timer and real time passing data to my datagridview. thanks

Comment: This is same as my code, you used simple for loops while I used linq.

Comment: Yes. I am not good in Linq. But I tried your code also. I coulnd get result. but thaks Reza so much

Comment: This solution will have problem with readonly columns, also will have problems with reordered columns, also will have problems when a column of table is not present in grid, while my post covers these issues.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that it also is highly inefficient.