# Button click event in quickly refreshed DataGridView not consistently firing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a WinForms application where i use a `DataGridView` to display some data which is rapidly changing. I use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer()` with an interval of 50-100 ms to limit the update frequency of the `DataSource` and thus the UI.
I want to be able to delete rows in the grid so i have added a `DataGridViewButtonColumn` which i handle through the `CellContentClick` event. The problem is, that this event doesn't fire consistently due to the rather 'high' update frequency. Sometimes it fires, sometimes it doesn't.
Is there any way to get around this issue where i keep the buttons in the grid and still use a fast UI update rate (around 100 ms max.)?

This is a condensed version of my code:

```
private IBindingList _bindingList = new BindingList<MyData>();
private BindingSource _bindingSource = new BindingSource(_bindingList, null);

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView.DataSource = _bindingSource;

    var uiTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    uiTimer.Interval = 100;
    uiTimer.Tick += uiTimer_Tick;
    uiTimer.Start();
}

private void uiTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Get the underlying list of the binding source
     var list = ((IList<MyData>)_bindingSource.List);

     // Manipulate affected items in the bindinglist here...

     // Update DataGridView
     _bindingSource.ResetBindings(false);

}

private void dataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
            e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button clicked!");
        // Do remove stuff here...
    }
}
```

Comment: I think its better not to rebind data to datagrid view, instead you can update the data in your datagrid veiw. You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33164169/3110834) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33163921/3110834) helpful

Comment: Manually updating the cells did the trick. A bit more tedious, but whatever works :o) Thanks alot!

Comment: Happy to hear that it helped you to solve the problem, here in stackoverflow you can vote up as many answer as helpful by click on up arrow near the answer, this way it will be more useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas...

1. instead of _bindingSource.ResetBindings(false);

perhaps its more efficient to use SuspendBinding/ResumeBinding combo

```
_bindingSource.SuspendBinding();
// affected items in the bindinglist here...
_bindingSource.ResumeBinding();
```

Also make sure _bindingList is not modified elsewhere but in the timer event

2. [*Preferred*] Use Reactive Extensions instead of the timer to buffer your updates http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html

Comment: Unfortunately, the first idea did not have any effect on this issue, but thanks for suggesting it.